# Google API I can't get my position I get just another position

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I can't get my position and I don't know why, just I get another position

My code is here:

```
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>

  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 6
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };

        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
        handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
      });
    } else {
      // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
  }

  function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
    infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                          'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                          'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, your code indicates my current position if I allow the Geolocation request. 
If the current position of yours are incorrect, that is the problem of HTML5 Geolocation API. Not related with Google Maps API.